# Xubuntu: poptrayminus is not working (python neither)

Tags: xubuntu, python

I just installed Xubuntu 16 LTS but I can't run poptayminus (written in Python). It did work in Lubuntu which I used before. This is probably a Python problem: I can't start Python either. the whisker menu lists Python (v3.2) which is non-existent. usr/bin lists Python 2.7 and 3.5 but if I start these, nothing happens.
How can I fix this?

Comment: It is unclear what you installed and from where. Please add links to your question and steps to reproduce.